# ERROR make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: compiling, make, configure, makefile

I am getting error for "make" command" as below:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Here are the two command lines after downloading a Git repository:

```
 ./configure --enable-sky130-pdk
 make
```

There was one error with regards to 'magic' tool install- please see below:

checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 3.4

configure: Found tools: klayout magic netgen irsim openlane qflow xschem xcircuit

checking for magic... no configure: error: You need 'magic' to generate the needed various cell views.

I have not installed magic yet. I tried the sudo- see below for error

sudo apt-get -y install magic

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package magic

Note: I did not have this errors prior to ubuntu reinstall.

I agree, that the error message is not related to Ubuntu. The error message, yes, is suggesting about missing magic package. Next, I will see if magic-install related instructions at opencircuitdesign.com/open_pdks can bring us closer to solution.

Comment: Did `./configure --enable-sky130-pdk` complete *successfully*? examine its terminal output for error messages, and/or look in the `config.log` file

Comment: There was one error- please see below:       checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 3.4... python3
.
configure: Found tools: klayout magic netgen irsim openlane qflow xschem xcircuit
checking for magic... no
configure: error: You need 'magic' to generate the needed various cell views.

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question

Comment: @Dervish007 Have you installed magic then? i.e. sudo apt-get -y install magic

Comment: I doubt that the error message is referring to the Ubuntu `magic` package - it's more likely a reference to a missing PDK submodule. Did you run the submodule make command(s) suggested at [Using the SkyWater Open Source PDK](https://github.com/google/skywater-pdk#using-the-skywater-open-source-pdk) after cloning the git repo?

Comment: I agree, that the error message is not related to Ubuntu. The error message, yes, is suggesting about missing magic package. Next, I will see if magic-install related instructions at http://opencircuitdesign.com/open_pdks/ can bring closer to solution. I plan to post an update about it.

Comment: new error after running ./configure :                   configure: error: cannot find /bin/csh---cannot compile!

Answer (score 0):

the error "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." has gone away after enabling "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)" under  Tab in the "Software & Updates".

I guess that this fix enabled missing packages.